# Selenium Headless chrome runs much slower

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I have a class for Selenium parser:

```py
class DynamicParser(Parser):
    """Selenium Parser with processing JS"""
    driver: Chrome = None

    def __init__(self, driver_path='./chromedriver', headless=True):
        chrome_options = Options()
        if headless:
            chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
            chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")

        # bypass OS security
        chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        # overcome limited resources
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        # don't tell chrome that it is automated
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option(
            "excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
        # disable images
        prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

        # Setting Capabilities
        capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
        capabilities['acceptSslCerts'] = True
        capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True

        self.driver = Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options,
                             executable_path=driver_path, desired_capabilities=capabilities)

    def goto(self, url: str):
        """Goes to specified URL"""
        self.driver.get(url)

    def get_seller_name(self) -> str:
        """Returns seller's name"""
        offer_actions_tag = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name(
            'offer-user__actions')
        profile_link_tag = offer_actions_tag.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
        return profile_link_tag.text.strip()
```

Also I have a test script, which creates `DynamicParser`, goes to some page and calls `.get_seller_name()`.

I noticed that when I run Chromedriver headless, it runs much slower, so i tested it using `time python3 test.py`.

Output for headless chrome:

```
python3 test.py  2,98s user 0,94s system 3% cpu 2:04,65 total
```

Output for non-headless chrome:

```
python3 test.py  1,48s user 0,33s system 47% cpu 3,790 total
```

As we can see, headless chrome runs almost 33 times slower!

Chrome version: `83.0.4103.116`

Chromedriver version: `83.0.4103.39`

I don't really understand what's the problem. When I developed my previous application, headless chrome worked fast enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the problem. It was

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
```

I supposed that it should have unlimit chrome resources, but it definitely doesn't work in this case.

Comment: This answer is community wiki, so please add some details/explanation if you know what was the problem.

Comment: Hey!

Do you mean you shouldn't have added that argument to your chrome_options??

Answer (score 0):

When running headless driver you can also use those settings for the performance improvement.

```
browser_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
browser_options.headless = True
image_preferences = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
browser_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", image_preferences)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already have those in `__init__`, right after `#disable images`

Answer (score 0):

I found that none of these worked for me.

However, changing `options.add_argument('--headless')` to `options.add_argument('--headless=new')` made a huge difference and seemed to have entirely fixed the problem.